# how to make the plot, but not open a new tab in bokeh?

Tags: plot, bokeh

Here is what I do to make plots with `bokeh`

```
p1=make_plot(df)    
output_file("out.html", title="out example")
show(p1)
```

This always open a new tab to refresh the plot, but I do not want that. It's enough to just refresh a tab with previous version of the plot.

How can I stop `show()` to open a new tab and just make the new plot?

I have tried the option `broweser=None` or `broweser=''` but that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for save(), not show()

```
from bokeh.io import output_file,show,save
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file('out.html',title='out example')
fig = figure()
show(fig) # will pop up in the browser
a = raw_input() # just press any key to continue
fig.line(range(10),range(10))
save(fig) # you can refresh your browser tab to see the change
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`save`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html#bokeh.io.save) instead of `show` in the last step. This will save the plot instead of opening it in browser.

```
from bokeh.io import save

p1=make_plot(df)    
output_file("out.html", title="out example")
save(p1)
```